# How to check if all the digits in a number are prime or not.?

Tags: java

How to check if all the digits in a number are prime or not.?

For example:

**input:** 2375

**Ouput:** Yes ,it is prime

**Input:** 2345

**Output:** Not a prime

Comment: Split the number into its components, loop over the components testing if they are prime.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        int n=1235;
        int r,i,s,flag=0;

        while(n>0)
        {
            r=n%10;  /* extracting the digits one by one */
            n=n/10;
            flag=0;

            s=(int) Math.sqrt(r);  /*taking the sqrt of extracted number */

            for(i=2;i<=s;i++)    /*iterating from 2 to sqrt of the extracted number, if the extracted number is divisible by any number in the iteration then it is not prime*/
            {
                if(r%i==0)
                {
                    flag=1;      /*if it is divisible break out */
                    break;
                }   
            }

            if(flag==1)      /*break out of while loop also if it is divisible */
            {
                System.out.println("not prime");
                break;
            }


        }

        if(flag==0)              /*if the loop completed without breaking, it means the number is prime */
            System.out.println("prime"); 



    }
}
```

I have explained the code in comments